# Understanding dc.js group reduce methods

Tags: javascript, dc.js

I am learning dc.js and javascript in general. and reading though their annotated source on their homepage: https://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/docs/stock.html. I am not quite understanding how this particular section works.

```
var ndx = crossfilter(data);
var all = ndx.groupAll();


var yearlyDimension = ndx.dimension(function (d) {
    return d3.time.year(d.dd).getFullYear();
});



     var yearlyPerformanceGroup = yearlyDimension.group().reduce(
    /* callback for when data is added to the current filter results */
    function (p, v) {
        ++p.count;
        p.absGain += v.close - v.open;
        p.fluctuation += Math.abs(v.close - v.open);
        p.sumIndex += (v.open + v.close) / 2;
        p.avgIndex = p.sumIndex / p.count;
        p.percentageGain = p.avgIndex ? (p.absGain / p.avgIndex) * 100 : 0;
        p.fluctuationPercentage = p.avgIndex ? (p.fluctuation / p.avgIndex) * 100 : 0;
        return p;
    },
    /* callback for when data is removed from the current filter results */
    function (p, v) {
        --p.count;
        p.absGain -= v.close - v.open;
        p.fluctuation -= Math.abs(v.close - v.open);
        p.sumIndex -= (v.open + v.close) / 2;
        p.avgIndex = p.count ? p.sumIndex / p.count : 0;
        p.percentageGain = p.avgIndex ? (p.absGain / p.avgIndex) * 100 : 0;
        p.fluctuationPercentage = p.avgIndex ? (p.fluctuation / p.avgIndex) * 100 : 0;
        return p;
    },
    /* initialize p */
    function () {
        return {
            count: 0,
            absGain: 0,
            fluctuation: 0,
            fluctuationPercentage: 0,
            sumIndex: 0,
            avgIndex: 0,
            percentageGain: 0
        };
    }
);
```

The reduce method seems to contain 3 arguments: (previous, current, initial).

There are functions being passed into each of these argument in this particular example, but each of those function has two parameters of p and v...What exactly is getting passed into p and v? and how does this reduce function know which one to call?

Comment: Here's the crossfilter documentation for [group.reduce()](https://github.com/crossfilter/crossfilter/wiki/API-Reference#group_reduce). The three arguments to reduce are add, remove, and initialize. Add and reduce take previous and current.

Comment: I understand that part of it, but for each argument, it is passing a function that takes two parameters...What goes into these parameters?

Comment: It's very much like [Array.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce), at least if you only consider the add function. Previous (`p`) is the result value being reduced, and current (`v`) is the current record/row being looked at. The remove function should do the opposite of add, and happens later when stuff is filtered out of the chart.